# How to replicate a task in map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, task, replication

I have a mapreduce program and running on Hadoop-2.9 with 1 master and 5 slaves. In this program, processing of each record is one task. So every task is computed by one mapper.

**Question**:

How to replicate task so that a task will be computed by two mappers? Or each task will be done twice.

Comment: I read about `Counters` for this question. Do you know `Counter` is really solution or not?

Comment: You want all your data to be processed twice, separately? Can I ask why? It's an unusual use case to say the least.

Comment: Very detailed. I'm doing verification work on intermediate result of mappers. So, I want to replicate task between two mapper. yes, indeed data to be processed twice.

Comment: I still really don't understand and can't imagine a situation where this is necessary, but I guess https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html is what you want.